After clone image upload and date picker is not working
Image upload and date picker not working after clone
I want to duplicate the HTML section when I click add more button
After clone the date picker and image uploads are not working. but if I manually duplicate them they are working.what could be the solution for this


// qualification clone
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#addbtn').click(function() {
    $('.duplicate-row:last-child').clone().appendTo('.multi-area');
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.removebtn', function() {
    if ($('.duplicate-row').length > 1) {
      $(this).parents('.duplicate-row').remove();
    }
  });
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.2/css/all.min.css"  />
<div class="multi-area">
  <div class="row duplicate-row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Course Name" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Institute Name" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <h6 class="headings">Course Completion Date</h6>
      <!-- Date Picker Input -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="datepicker date input-group">
          <input type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control" id="reservationDate" />
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <span class="input-group-text px-4 gap-3"><i class="fa-solid
                            fa-calendar"></i>Pick Date</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <!-- DEnd ate Picker Input -->
      <h6 class="headings">
        Education Certificate
        <span>
                         (Recommended file Dimensions: 200 X 200
                        Pixels)</span>
      </h6>
      <div class="ux-a-file-upload">
        <input type="file" name="file name" class="ux-js-a-file-upload__input-file
                        ux-a-file-upload__input-file" />
        <div class="input">
          <input type="text" class="ux-js-a-file-upload__input-text
                          ux-a-file-upload__input-text" />
        </div>
        <button class="ux-a-file-button rounded-end">
                        <i
                          class="fa-solid fa-cloud-arrow-up me-2"
                          style="color: #0c061e"></i>chose file
                      </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 text-end">
      <span class="removebtn">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"></i>
                  </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




I mader you a snippet. Please change it to include the add button

Where is the datepicker code?

Use the true argument to .clone() to copy event listeners.

And PS, it's "choose file" not "chose file".
